# Could not hide unwanted Options Page navigation items from Tools-Options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working on Visual Studio Isolated Shell Project.
I [saw on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx) that in order to remove Options Pages, I have to edit the .pkgundef file.

I disabled the Database Tools package

```
// Visual Database Tools Package
 [$RootKey$\Packages\{220A4C17-7E7C-4663-BBCC-5E607C6543CD}]
```

The package is gone, I don't see any window or menu command for that. But when I launch the Options dialog from Tools menu, I see the navigation item and when I choose that, I see the "Error page"

[image]

How do I hide the navigation item?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/102a67e4-824a-4163-a6a5-8522083f926d/remove-packages-from-the-tools-options-page-isolated-shell-vs2010?forum=vsx).
In my specific scenario, I had to add the following key to .pkgundef file.

```
[$RootKey$\ToolsOptionsPages\Database Tools]
```